# Partition Oozie table for Faster Purge

Tags: mysql, hadoop, database-administration, oozie

We run oozie and the jobs are scheduled too frequently that causes the database to grow really fast which in turn leads to slowness of the db.

So we started to purge records frequently and with time purge ( i.e delete * from table ) introduced locks which started again causing slowness in the app.

We started looking at options like parititioning the table based on start_time or end_time field in the tables but we hit a dead end when we realized we cannot partition a mysql table on a key thats not a primiary key.

Sample table desc

```
CREATE TABLE `WF_JOBS` (

  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conf` mediumtext,
  `group_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `run` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bean_type` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth_token` text,
  `created_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proto_action_conf` text,
  `sla_xml` text,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wf_instance` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `I_WF_JOBS_DTYPE` (`bean_type`),
  KEY `I_WF_JOBS_END_TIME` (`end_time`),
  KEY `I_WF_JOBS_EXTERNAL_ID` (`external_id`),
  KEY `I_WF_JOBS_LAST_MODIFIED_TIME` (`last_modified_time`),
  KEY `I_WF_JOBS_STATUS` (`status`)

)
```

Any clue on how to purge or drop tables without causing locks, or is there a way to partition tables in mysql  without creating any more keys so that we can drop the partition directly

-jabir